# How to configure proxy server on Windows Server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, proxy

I'm new to Windows Server and as I understand, a proxy server is an intermediary between a client computer and the internet.

On client computer I can set proxy server address and port inside Settings -> Network & Internet -> Proxy page, but I don't know how to obtain the address and the port from the server machine. Do I need to download the proxy server from internet?

My server machine is running Windows Server 2016.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Server doesn't have any built-in proxy functionality; if you want to set up a proxy, you need additional software (or a different OS).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you recommend me an additional software that can be used to set up a proxy?

Comment: You can try Squid, it's commonly used on Linux but it's available for Windows too.